# Проблема с открытие файлов загруженных на сервер в Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, fileupload, resources

Есть Controller в котором через `@GetMapping` обрабатываю страницу

```
orders/{id}/upload
```

где реализован следующий функционал.

Выводится список файлов со ссылками на эти файлы из директории

```
src/main/resources/static/layout/{id}/
```

и реализована форма multipart form, через которою происходит загрузка файлов на сервер в указанную выше папку в `RestController` через `@PostMapping`.

**Проблема такая:**
Когда я загружаю файл на сервер, он попадает в список файлов, но если я перехожу по ссылке, выпадает ошибка 404, хотя файл на сервере есть.

Я перезагружаю сервер **и ссылка начинает работать** (*адрес ссылки не меняется*).

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

```
@Controller
public class OrderController {
  @GetMapping("/orders/{id}/upload")
  public String upload(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("order_number", id);
    String directory = "src/main/resources/static/layout/" + id + "/";
    File file = new File(directory);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    File[] listFiles = file.listFiles();
    model.addAttribute("listfile", listFiles);
    return "upload";
  }
}
```

.

```
@Service
public class FileUploadService {
    public void uploadFile(MultipartFile file, long id) throws IOException {
        File uploadFile = new File("/Users/prisukhin/Documents/printing/src/main/resources/static/layout/" + id + "/" + file.getOriginalFilename());
        if(file != null) {
            file.transferTo(uploadFile);
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
@RestController
public class FileUploadRestController {

    @Autowired
    FileUploadService fileUploadService;

    @PostMapping("/orders/{id}/upload")
    public RedirectView fileUpload(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id, @RequestParam MultipartFile file_form, Model model) throws IOException {
        fileUploadService.uploadFile(file_form, id);
        return new RedirectView("/orders/{id}/upload");
    }
```

часть файла upload.html

```
<table class="table table-hover">    
  <tbody th:each="l : ${listfile}">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a th:text="${#strings.substringAfter(l, '/layout/'+order_number+'/')}" th:href="@{'../../'}+${#strings.substringAfter(l, '/static/')}" target="_blank"></a>. 
      </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 <form th:attr="action=@{'/orders/'} + ${order_number} + @{'/upload'}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="upload-form mx-auto">
   <div class="input-group mb-3">
     <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file_form" />
       <div class="input-group-append">
         <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Загрузить</button>
       </div>
   </div>
 </form>
```

Whitelabel error page

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Sep 23 11:50:06 MSK 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Debug информация

```
2022-09-23 11:50:02.881 DEBUG 58415 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/orders/45/upload", parameters={multipart}
2022-09-23 11:50:02.947 DEBUG 58415 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.prisukhin.integral.controllers.FileUploadRestController#fileUpload(long, MultipartFile, Model)
2022-09-23 11:50:03.024 DEBUG 58415 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.view.RedirectView        : View [RedirectView], model {}
2022-09-23 11:50:03.038 DEBUG 58415 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 302 FOUND
2022-09-23 11:50:03.046 DEBUG 58415 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/orders/45/upload", parameters={}
2022-09-23 11:50:03.047 DEBUG 58415 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.prisukhin.integral.controllers.OrderController#upload(long, Model)
2022-09-23 11:50:03.065 DEBUG 58415 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2022-09-23 11:50:03.668 DEBUG 58415 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/css/style.css", parameters={}
2022-09-23 11:50:03.672 DEBUG 58415 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/img/logo-1.png", parameters={}
2022-09-23 11:50:03.675 DEBUG 58415 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2022-09-23 11:50:03.675 DEBUG 58415 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2022-09-23 11:50:03.691 DEBUG 58415 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2022-09-23 11:50:03.693 DEBUG 58415 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2022-09-23 11:50:03.728 DEBUG 58415 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK


2022-09-23 11:50:06.162 DEBUG 58415 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] **o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/layout/45/0000005z.xml", parameters={}
2022-09-23 11:50:06.163 DEBUG 58415 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2022-09-23 11:50:06.164 DEBUG 58415 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2022-09-23 11:50:06.165 DEBUG 58415 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2022-09-23 11:50:06.173 DEBUG 58415 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2022-09-23 11:50:06.177 DEBUG 58415 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2022-09-23 11:50:06.226 DEBUG 58415 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2022-09-23 11:50:06.229 DEBUG 58415 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404**
```

Comment: а где у вас контроллер, который пытается обработать `/layout/45/0000005z.xml`?

Comment: извиняюсь...он как раз таки есть... запрос приходит на `ResourceHttpRequestHandler`, пытается в папке `resources` найти `/layout/45/0000005z.xml`.  не находит и выдаёт `404`....причем тут `@GetMapping("/orders/{id}/upload")`?

Comment: запрос же `/orders/45/upload` успешно обрабатывается `com.prisukhin.integral.controllers.OrderController#upload(long, Model)`

Comment: Все...понял о чем ваш вопрос...сорри.... Ну и это не вопрос собственно...Ведет себя он так, потому что папка `/src/main/resources/` не предназначена для того чтобы в нее загружались пользовательские файлы

Comment: данная папка в исходниках предназначена для ресурсов приложения. После сборки все содержимое данной папки перепещается в папки `target/classes`(в случае с maven) или `build/classes`(в случае с gradle) вместе с скомпилированными классами и импортированными зависимостями ... откуда и запускается...

Comment: именно поэтому вы ничего не видите до перезапуска...потому что вы `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` смотрит в папку `target/classes/`, а вы загружаете  в `src`... только в `target` ничего загружать не надо ибо это временная папка...загружать нужно в отдельную папку и настраивать отдачу для данной папки.

Comment: сейчас нормальный ответ оформлю

Comment: Спасибо большое, я вечером попробую. Дня 2 наверное мучился над этим вопросом

Comment: Если возникнут вопросы - пишите их под ответом, чтобы мне пришли уведомления. Если все ок и ответ помог вам, то можете поставить галочку слева от ответа. См. справку [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Папка `/src/main/resources/` не предназначена для того чтобы в нее загружались пользовательские файлы.
Данная папка в исходниках предназначена для ресурсов приложения.

После сборки все содержимое данной папки перепещается в

- папку `target/classes`
  вместе с скомпилированными классами и импортированными зависимостями
  *(если проект собирается maven)*
- или в папку `build/resources`
  *(если проект собирается  gradle)*
  скомпилированные классы перемещаются в `build/classes`

откуда(`target`/`build`) и запускается приложение.

Именно поэтому вы ничего не видите до перезапуска.

Когда Вы делаете запрос `/layout/45/0000005z.xml` Ваш `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` пытается его найти не по пути `/Users/prisukhin/Documents/printing/src/main/resources/static/layout/45/0000005z.xml` (как Вы того ожидаете), а по пути

- `/Users/prisukhin/Documents/printing/target/static/layout/45/0000005z.xml`
  *(если проект собирается maven)*
- `/Users/prisukhin/Documents/printing/build/resources/static/layout/45/0000005z.xml`
  *(если проект собирается  gradle)*

Только умоляю Вас, не стоит ничего загружать

- ни в `target/classes/`
- ни в `build/resources/`

Они также не предназначены для заргузки пользовательских файлов.
Это временные папки для сборки проекта

### Как поступить?

Вам нужно создать отдельную папку вне папки с исходными кодами и вне папок для сборки проекта.
Если хотите чтобы она находилась рядом, можете создать что-то вроде:

- `/Users/prisukhin/Documents/printing/storage/`

И настроить отдачу статики на нее.

Для этого добавьте в файл настройки MVC (класс конфигурации имплементирующий `WebMvcConfigurer`) в метод `addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)` следующие строки:

```
registry
    .addResourceHandler("/storage/**")
    .addResourceLocations("file:/Users/prisukhin/Documents/printing/storage/")
    ;
```

После чего нужно поправить контроллер

```
@Controller
public class OrderController {
  @GetMapping("/orders/{id}/upload")
  public String upload(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("order_number", id);
    String directory = "/Users/prisukhin/Documents/printing/storage/layout/" + id + "/";
    File file = new File(directory);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    File[] listFiles = file.listFiles();
    model.addAttribute("listfile", listFiles);
    return "upload";
  }
}
```

Сервис

```
@Service
public class FileUploadService {
    public void uploadFile(MultipartFile file, long id) throws IOException {
        File uploadFile = new File("/Users/prisukhin/Documents/printing/storage/layout/" + id + "/" + file.getOriginalFilename());
        if(file != null) {
            file.transferTo(uploadFile);
        }
    }
}
```

ну и ссылки поправить...

Они должны будут ссылаться на `/storage/layout/45/0000005z.xml`

---

#### Конфигурирование

Данный же путь лучше положить в application.properties, добавив строку, наподобии:

```
app.storage.path=/Users/prisukhin/Documents/printing/storage/
```

После чего Вы сможете её внедрить в Сервис (и куда угодно) следующим образом

```
@Value("${app.storage.path}")
String storagePath;
```

В сервисе:

```
@Service
public class FileUploadService {

    @Value("${app.storage.path}")
    String storagePath;

    public void uploadFile(MultipartFile file, long id) throws IOException {
        File uploadFile = new File(storagePath + "layout/" + id + "/" + file.getOriginalFilename());
        if(file != null) {
            file.transferTo(uploadFile);
        }
    }
}
```

В контроллере:

```
@Controller
public class OrderController {

  @Value("${app.storage.path}")
  String storagePath;

  @GetMapping("/orders/{id}/upload")
  public String upload(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("order_number", id);
    String directory = storagePath + "layout/" + id + "/";
    File file = new File(directory);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    File[] listFiles = file.listFiles();
    model.addAttribute("listfile", listFiles);
    return "upload";
  }
}
```

После чего вы сможете легко перемещать данное приложение не беспокоясь о том, что Ваше приложение прибито гвоздями к вашему личному компьютеру. Вы всегда сможете указать нужный путь для нужной среды и оно сможет работать одновременно как на вашем компьютере так и на сервере где нибудь в `/var/www/`

Comment: Огромное спасибо за такой развернутый ответ, все работает прекрасно.

Comment: @Алексей, рад) В таком случае можете галочку слева от вопроса поставить) Тут так принято спасибо говорить )